# Connectomeviewer cannot import dipy module

Tags: python, import, module, python-import

Though I installed dipy but just cannot import, also I installed dipy first so it's not in the folder of connectomeviewer. Do I need to move dipy to connectomeviewer folder or do something else?

My import looks like this:

```
from cviewer.libs.dipy.io import trackvis as tv
from cviewer.libs.dipy.core import track_performance as pf
from cviewer.libs.dipy.core import track_metrics as tm
from cviewer.libs.dipy.viz import fos
```

Comment: Can you please explain how exactly did you installed it?

Comment: It was just standard installation,  I used the code like sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install connectomeviewer

Comment: Before that I've already installed dipy

Answer (score 0):

Maybe importing directly from dipy would work for you?

```
from dipy.io import trackvis as tv
from dipy.core import track_performance as pf
from dipy.core import track_metrics as tm
from dipy.viz import fos
```